# Configure UI-Router for Multiple Modules

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making a project in Angular 1.4, and i'm using ui-router, I have split my project in several sub-modules, there's one 'parent' module (not sure if i'm using the concept of parent and child right) and several 'child' modules.

The 'parent' has routes for the global login, and the two main menus of each group, the groups are: guides, projects; each one of them has it's own 'child' modules some of them are: guides[Web, Mobile, Desktop], projects[Business, Community]. Each module has it's own routes, and what i want is to be able to route the app though each module.

The main routes are:

```
/
/login

/guides
/guides/login
/guides/web
/guides/mobile
/guides/desktop

/projects
/projects/login
/projects/business
/projects/community
```

The site has somehow same login concept of SE, people can have a global account, or a single account on a specific module.

What i've tried so far if to make the routes as Doc says:

```
angular.module('main', ['main.guides', 'main.projects']).config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
        state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: './views/index.html',
            controller: 'IndexCtrl'
        }).
        state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: './views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }).
        state('guides', {
            url: '/guides',
            templateUrl: './views/guides-menu.html',
            controller: 'GuidesCtrl'
        }).
        state('projects', {
            url: '/projects',
            templateUrl: './views/projects-menu.html',
            controller: 'ProjectsCtrl'
        });
});

angular.module('main.guides', []).config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
        state('main.guides-login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: './views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }).
        state('main.guides-menu', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: './views/menu.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }).
        state('main.guides-web', {
            url: '/web',
            templateUrl: './views/web/list.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl'
        }).
        state('main.guides-mobile', {
            url: '/web',
            templateUrl: './views/mobile/list.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl'
        });
});

angular.module('main.projects', []).config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.
        state('main.projects-login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: './views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }).
        state('main.projects-business', {
            url: '/business',
            templateUrl: './views/business/list.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl'
        }).
        state('main.projects-menu', {
            url: '/business',
            templateUrl: './views/menu.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl'
        }).
        state('main.projects-community', {
            url: '/business',
            templateUrl: './views/community/list.html',
            controller: 'ListCtrl'
        })
});
```

But don't know how to access to those urls... also would like some opinion about this approach, would there be a better practice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a plunkr to demo your states. I altered the code to use templates instead of templateUrl but that shouldn't change what you are trying to figure out.  I made some assumptions about your layout based on the urls provided.  If you pop it out into the external viewer you can see the urls being used. Find it here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/9lPQ3GlmH0AEqhzX7lj9?p=preview

Urls in the ui-router are used as part of what specifies the state.  So when you want /projects/business you have a state that is a child of projects that has a url  of /business.  Something like:

```
    state('projects.business', {
        url: '/business',
        template: '<div> projects business</div>',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'
    })
```

The dot notation in the state definition tells the ui router that this is child state of projects.  The url value provided is added to the parent state url.

I think your module strategy is solid. You just need to wrap your head about the parent child relationships used in the ui.router.

Comment: The one suggestion is have for breaking down your modules further would be to move the guides and projects state into the appropriate submodule. It makes sense to define a parent and all its direct children in the same module.

Comment: In the case that i have the scripts as separate files do i have to load all the scripts in the index of the project or just the ones that contain the modules?

Comment: You'll need to load all scripts in the index unless you are using some other mechanism to load the scripts dynamically like requirejs. I usually just load them in index and use a mini fixation tool to uglify and minimize the code for deployment. Note this is not the case for your templates.